# Accessing Honeywell-Box(HICC-P-2100X) IP Camera with c#?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, ip-camera

Nowadays I am using Honeywell IP camera for image processing application.But unfortunately I couldn't manage to open it using opencvsharp in c# programming.

So, I would like to share some part of my code and I am using ethernet cable to connect it directly(cable from my notebook to Ip camera).I defined static ip to my laptop and I am able to connect it using default ip configuration via internet explorer.But I am not able to connect and open this camera using c# programming.

I tried all relevant links to make it work as below.Any help would be highly apreciated.

```
string v2 = @"http://192.168.0.101:5060/h264"; 
CvCapture camera = new CvCapture(v2)

string v2 = @"http://admin:admin@192.168.0.101:564/h264";
string v2 = @"rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.101:564/h264";
string v2 = @"http://192.168.0.101:564/img/video.mjpeg";
string v2 = @"http://admin:admin@192.168.0.101:564/img/video.mjpeg";
string v2 = @"http://192.168.0.101:564/img/video.mjpeg";
string v2 = @"http://192.168.0.101:564/img/video.asf";
string v2 = @"http://192.168.0.101:564/img/video.mjpeg";
```

All these methods are defined according to related link below(I tried almost all but I couldn be successful
[http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_183-how-to-connect-to-your-honeywell-ip-camera-onvif.html``](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_183-how-to-connect-to-your-honeywell-ip-camera-onvif.html%60%60)

[related image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTfHi.gif)

Comment: Not c# but maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324785/ip-camera-access-using-opencv?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/dbf7400d-fbe9-e770-57aa-f63bc507c917.htm JPGStream to capture your video.

```
_videoSource = new JPEGStream(ConnectionString);


_videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
_videoSource.Start();
```

And after capture you can process you images with opencv.

Comment: But I would like to inform you that "CvCapture" method is working with my webcam.I defined as "CvCapture camera = new CvCapture(0)" and it opens my webcam for image processing application correctly.But unfortunately I couldn't apply same method for ip cam.I think something wrong on my definitions(links) for this camera as you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ONVIF DEVICE MANAGER**
then you can find the url of your ip camera
like: 
rtsp://192.168.1.188/media?stream=0