# Connect to sricam IP cameras using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ip-camera

**Update**: I am using **sricam SP019** IP(Wireless) camera.
I have been able to find the RTSP URL for my camera: "**rtsp://IP_ADDRESS:554/onvif1**" and also managed to play it in VLC and the onvifer Android app provided.

The app also provided the following info - 
 - Encoding: H264
 - Transport Protocol: RTP/RTSP/TCP
 - RTP packets received: some non-zero number
 - RTP packets lost: 0
 - RTSP port: 554

However, **I still keep getting the error** shown below.

===========================================

I am currently working on a project that requires me to interface with an IP camera (Company name: **sricam**) using openCV 3.3.1.

**Already tried**:

I have posted in the openCV forum ([here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/182400/connecting-to-sricam-ip-cameras-using-opencv/)) but have not received any reply yet. I also tried all options in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324785/ip-camera-access-using-opencv) but keep getting this error related to the Gstreamer library.-

[image]

**My question**:

It would be extremely helpful if someone can just point me in the right direction as a minimum.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you open the video feed with ffmpeg?

Comment: How about asking the vendor? Please show the code you are using - an error message on its own is not much use. How about telling us the camera model? Come on - if you want someone to help you, make it easy for them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell- I have used almost the same code as mentioned in the link in my question ( just posting it here again - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324785/ip-camera-access-using-opencv ) ... I have tried all the methods suggested by people there ...and yes, I am going to ask the vendor next , was hoping someone might have the answer before I did that.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to camera URL there should be some default value in documentation (but it might be changed on configuration of camera). I guess that it will be best to start looking there.

Did you try looking on this page?

https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Sricam

Comment: I have just updated the question with my camera model : sricam SP019.
I have already checked the list, my camera model is not there...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. 
It worked to me ( OSX, sricam sp005 )

import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://[IP_CAM_ADD]", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

Hope to be helpful to somebody